# Use Sencha Fashion to generate new theme without the javascript source code

Tags: css, extjs, sass, sencha-fashion

I have a Cmd-generated 6.0.2 application that is running at about 200 customers on-premise servers. I would like to allow the customers to select a base color and a text color, (e.g. #c0ffee and #facade), and call an API running on our server (not on a dev PC!), that takes the SCSS, sets $base-color:dynamic(#c0ffee) and $color:dynamic(#facade), generates the resulting CSS and returns that to the customer, where it is stored on the server alongside the app.

It is really easy to implement this by copying the whole project, including the javascript sources, to the server, calling sencha app build production, and then return the content of the generated CSS files. But since it's a server API, I would like to reduce the footprint, by not always compiling and then discarding the javascript, and at best, not even needing the javascript on the server.

It would be really nice if someone could tell me how I can, using sencha Cmd, generate a single SCSS file that contains all styles required for the app, such that I would only have to search/replace in that file the $base-color and $color definition, and how to, after successfully replacing it, call sencha fashion to only generate a single new CSS file from that SCSS file.